# Who does 'who' refer to?

Tags: relative-pronouns, parsing, attachment-ambiguity

> Tom plays basketball daily unlike Sam, who is a very busy man

Is the above sentence correct?

So 'who' always relates to 'Sam' or the nearest noun (& not Tom)?

Comment: To make *who* refer to "Tom", then "Tom plays basketball daily, who unlike Sam is a very active man."

Answer (score 1):

The question pronoun 'who' is placed after Sam and that too defined by the comma in this sentence. Indeed, it talks about *Sam* and **not** Tom.

In this sentence, it's clearly defined that *unlike Sam...who....* so it leaves no ambiguity in understanding the sentence. That said, yes, you are right.